PySide2 QWebEngineView does not play mp4, mkv, avi, mov and wmv video files
I just write a simple applications for Windows using PySide2 and Python 3.8 that is a reduced web browser (it can not navigate everywhere but only in some specific web pages) and it has to open html pages embedding audio or video files or just pointing to audio and video files. Everything works apart for the major part of video files it has to support. In practice, instead of playing mkv, avi, mov and wmv files the only thing I can do with them is download them. It plays well only webm video files and seems that it could play also mp4 video files because it opens them but it does not start them to play. Seems as it has no permission to do that (not by my side) or that some video codecs is missing. I just tryed to move to PySide6 but at the moment I am not able to fix other problems not present on PySide2. Did anyone had similar problems? Thanks, Massimo

What OS? Note that if you're on Windows you may need to install further codecs.

Yes, I am on Windows, it should work also on Linux. Well... in my PC I normally play mp4 files using VLC and also in firefox directly.

VLC is irrelevant, as it uses its own codecs. I now remembered that the default distribution of QWebEngine with PyQt doesn't provide proprietary codec support for license reasons, and that may be valid for PySide too. If you want that, you probably need to build Qt with the related flags (and the related PySide modules) on your own.

Probably is a stupid question but... why other libraries/frameworks have no problem at all to play mp4 videos? They should have the same licensing problems.

It's not that simple. First of all, some programs/libraries use the system multimedia backend (Qt did that for QtMultimedia until 6.4, when they switched to an internal ffmpeg build by default). When using internal codecs instead, the issue is with license compatibility, which can also have implications with local copyright law. Qt does provide proprietary codec support in QtWebEngine, it's just disabled in the standard release. In fact, if you want to redistribute a program with that support enabled, you should acquire licenses for those codecs (which is why they're disabled by default).

Ok, so the solution could be do not support mp4 files...

Again, it's not that simple. 1. MP4 is a container, it doesn't define the format it contains, and it can have one or more streams. The common scenario is one audio and one video stream (but, in theory, it can only contain one, and that one could even be a non-A/V one, such as a subtitle track); 2. the codec of each stream could be different, and you can have a perfectly valid MP4 file with a proprietary format for video and an open one for audio (or vice versa, both or none); 3. licenses expire, for instance a toolkit that provided MP3 decode/encode capabilities could've been illegal in »

» some countries when it was released, but after 2017 the same version would've become theoretically legal anywhere. For instance, libsndfile (a common multi purpose audio library) didn't provide support for general MPEG support (including the known "MP3" format) until 2022, since they're strict about licenses and codec implementation; 4. not supporting MP4 in general is therefore a wrong choice, as it would be limiting names based on their vowels. The world of multimedia formats/codecs is quite complex, I strongly suggest you to take [a lot of] your time to do careful research on the subject.
